# a dense set in plane

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Is there a dense set in $\Bbb{R^2}$ that every vertical line or horizontal line intersect in finite points. I think that we can consider $\Bbb{Q} ×\Bbb{Q}$ but every vertical line or horizontal line don't intersect in finite points.

Comment: Have you tried rotating the set a bit?

Comment: I think if A is a dense set in $\Bbb{R}$  then A×A is dense in $\Bbb{R^2}$ then we must find the dense  sets in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: But a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite, so there are always horizontal and vertical lines that intersect $A\times A$ in infinitely many points.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice hint. I like the idea and it's not that hard to work it out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can find an example by shifting each point in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ a little bit.

In particular, enumerate the points of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ as $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, ..., employing the fact that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is countable.

Now I claim that the set
$$
S = \left\{\left(x_n + \frac{\pi}{n}, y_n + \frac{\pi}{n}\right) : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
$$
works. 
Each horizontal or vertical line intersects at most one point of $S$. This follows from the fact that $\pi$ is irrational.

Furthermore, $S$ lies dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because $\mathbb{Q}^2$ lies dense in $\mathbb{R}$: any open ball in $ \mathbb{R}^2$ contains infinitely many points from $\mathbb{Q}^2$ and therefore also points from $S$ (for large enough $n$).

In fact, we can even find a dense set in the plane that contains no three collinear points. Such a set can be constructed by adding the points one by one; see [Timothy Gowers's blog](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/08/16/just-do-it-proofs/) for a nice explanation.

Comment: Very nice is your answer, very thanks.

Comment: Is $\{x_n +\frac{\pi}{n} \}$ dense in $\Bbb{R}$ ? I think it is dense in real numbers ,but with comment :
But a dense set in$ \Bbb{R^2}$ is infinite, so there are always horizontal and vertical lines that intersect A×A in infinitely many points